# How can I get back my router configuration in Ubuntu 16.04 server after shutdown?

Tags: networking, shutdown, nat

I shutdown my Ubuntu Server 16.04 after configuring it to the router using.

`sudo shutdown now`

The next day when I reboot, PC cannot update. My NAT configurations are gone.

When I type `sudo apt update`, it says

```
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
```

My PC doesn't seem to be able to access internet. Is there anything I can do about it since I am new to Ubuntu?

I have internet plugged in through an ethernet cable. But still, I cannot update.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add again you firewall rules, but wait, don't shutdown after that.

There are two programs to save and restore rules: `iptables-restore` `iptables-save` . Save rules and check if it will be restored automatically on reboot. If not - run `iptables-restore` in rc.local or better make it managed by systemd